# Android app requires to implement same dependencies as imported library

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to use my own library compiled into .aar. It works all fine as long as I keep dependencies used by library classed in app build.gradle. None of the app classess depends on those dependencies, however when I remove them from app build.gradle Im getting NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException i.e.:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials;
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials" on path: DexPathList`

In my library build.gradle I have these dependencies imported using api command, also have multiDex enabled in both app & library build.gradle.

Please, help me sort this out.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am also using Google Credentials in my library. Standalone library app works fine when imported as a module. But when I create an AAR file and use it in a different app, I get the similar error.